# Cannot change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to other than "Staging"

Tags: asp.net-core

I have "Development" set in my web.config, in the launchSettings.json (all profiles), and in the environment variables on Windows, but the application still shows the environment as "Staging". Also, even if I run Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") in something like RoslynPad, it also shows "Staging". I do not know where else I can look to set this value. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

The Environment Context is still "Staging".

[image]

Comment: It depends on how you're running and deploying it. Please see the documentation link here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Sorry, this is running locally on IIS Express.

Comment: Right-click your project and choose properties.Then check the Environment variables in Debug panel.Then save it and restart the visual studio.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I did exactly that and it worked! Now, the issue is, if I remove it completely from launchSettings.json (my end goal is to have it pull from the web.config's <environmentVariables /> section, and even after relaunching VS, it still is stuck on Development, even if a different environment is specified in the web.config. I understand that if this ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is missing, it defaults to Production. Grrr...

What else can cause this to "stick".

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I make sure to remove all environment variables defined on the OS. I also cleaned all bin folders. I still have the environment removed from launchsettings.json (as desired), and was able to get it to work using the config after a clean before building. This now seems to work. I do not know why it was so sticky before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Rena suggested, restarting VS helped fix the issue, and ensuring I did a clean and removing any/all environment variables defined on the OS now allows me to change the environment using the web.config.